Why UIAutomation WindowOpened Event does not fired?
I want to login to clickonce app programatically.
I have tried with following code.
This app is stock trading (kabus) app is developed by Japanese au Kabucom securities (https://kabu.com/tool/kabustation/default.html), so Login is required to open the trading window.
Also this app has delay between timing of "Showing ClickOnce update check dialog" and "Opening Login Window" because of clickonece.
I would like to run the code that to enter user id and password after open the login window certainly, so I want to detect WindowOpened Event.
But Now Nothing to happen even the event handler is added.
I also checked that WindowOpened Event has fired with AccEvent,
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/accessible-event-watcher)
but it is cannot handle on my C# code.
Note that This code is running on C# 9.0
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Text;


void onWindowOpened(object sender, AutomationEventArgs e)
{
    AutomationElement? element;
    try
    {
        element = sender as AutomationElement;
        if (element == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element is null");
        } else
        {
                Console.WriteLine("onWindowOpened!!");
                LoginKabucom();
        }
    }
    catch (ElementNotAvailableException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ElementNotAvailableException is happened");
    }
}



Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, AutomationElement.RootElement, TreeScope.Subtree, new AutomationEventHandler(onWindowOpened));
    KillKabuS(); // Ensure the stock trade software is killed before start.  
    var p = StartKabuS();



void KillKabuS()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        if (process.ProcessName.Contains("KabuS"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("KabuS is included");
            process.Kill(true);
            process.WaitForExit();
            break;
        }
    }
}

Process? StartKabuS()
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    var appref = "C:\\Users\\yuya\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\kabu.com\\kabuステーション.appref-ms";
    psi.FileName = appref;
    psi.UseShellExecute = true;
    var p = Process.Start(psi);
    return p;
}

void LoginKabucom(AutomationElement? elem)
{
   // do something related to login
}


WindowOpenedEvent + Subtree should see all Windows opened. You should try to provide a reproducing code that exhibit this behavior, we cannot test with this kabus thing.
